# PHP SoapClient types aren't reflecting inherited fields

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I have a WSDL file with two complex types, one extending the other. Something like:

```
<complexType name="Email">
    <sequence>
        <element name="replyTo"            type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="senderDisplayName"  type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="subject"            type="xsd:string"/>
         ...
    </sequence>
</complexType>
...
<complexType name="SingleEmailMessage">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:Email">
             <sequence>
                 <element name="plainTextBody" type="xsd:string"/>
                 ...
             </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Kudos if you recognize SalesForce object names. Now, if you send this into PHP SoapClient to be processed:

```
<?php 
    $client = new SoapClient('wsdl');
    $client->__getTypes();
?>
```

The SingleEmailMessage type will not reflect the fields from the type it extends, and there's no way to get the inheritance from the output of `getTypes`. Example output:

```
struct Email {
 string replyTo;
 string senderDisplayName;
 string subject;
}struct SingleEmailMessage {
 string plainTextBody;
}
```

I worked around this by editing the WSDL file to directly put the fields from Email into the SingleEmailMessage definition, but I think that there should be a better way.